# Why in my case are $gte and $lte not working in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I 've got the following document.

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("5d0e4232ccfb3ee9ac72a64d"), 
   "arraydatumobject" : {
       "datum" : ISODate("2010-01-02T00:00:00.000+0000")
   }
}
```

when i try to find the date with either $gte or $lte or even both i cant find the document.

so something like this:

```
db.getCollection("test").find(
   {
       arraydatumobject : { $elemMatch:{ datum :  {$gte : new ISODate("2008-01-02"), $lte : new ISODate("2011-01-02")}}}
   }
)
```

or this

```
db.getCollection("test").find(
    {
        arraydatumobject : {datum :  {$gte : new ISODate("2008-01-02"), $lte : new ISODate("2011-01-02")}}
    }
)
```

gets me nothing.

But when i use the following i do get a result.

```
db.getCollection("test").find(
    {
        arraydatumobject : {datum : new ISODate("2010-01-02")}
    }
)
```

i'm getting the document that i'm searching for...

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a given document of:

```
{ 
   "_id" : ObjectId("5d0e4232ccfb3ee9ac72a64d"), 
   "arraydatumobject" : {
       "datum" : ISODate("2010-01-02T00:00:00.000+0000")
   }
}
```

Your date range `find` query should be:

```
db.getCollection('test').find({ 
 'arraydatumobject.datum': {   // you have an object use obj.prop
    $gte : new ISODate("2008-01-02"), 
    $lte : new ISODate("2011-01-02")
  } 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second example should work, but you have a pair of curly braces missing there.

Also, you should compare using node.js `Date`s, not `ISODate`s

Try:

```
db.getCollection("test").find(
    {
        arraydatumobject : {datum :  {$gte : new Date(2008,2,1), $lte : new Date(2011, 2, 1)}}
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer Talha, indeed i forgot some curly brackets, but..... still not working the changing ISODate to Date did nothing. i'll update the code in the question so it's correct